# Correct kernel version to install on a Motion Computing m1400 tablet?

Tags: installation, usb

I am looking for some help installing Ubuntu on my m1400 Motion Computing tablet. I have tried the latest version (ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso) with the Universal USB installer (Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.4.exe) since I do not have an optical drive.

I booted from the USB and it gave an error saying "Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU". I do not know exactly what this means, so if anyone can point me towards another version of Ubuntu that is for my setup, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with that installation:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1154085
and:
http://debian.livejournal.com/346277.html